# Obter o título da página dentro de uma variável dinâmica em JavaScript

Tags: javascript

Olá!

Há um formulário que precisei colocar o *name* como dinâmico. Originalmente, esse *name* era apenas `registerformpopup`. Agora coloquei como `registerformpopup` + o título da página que varia de acordo com a página em que o usuário preencheu o formulário.

Isso funcionou perfeitamente.

```php
<form class="<?php if ( get_theme_mod( 'thim_auto_login', true ) ) {
    echo 'auto_login';
} 
?>" name="<?php echo 'registerformpopup' . get_the_title() ?>" 
    action="<?php echo esc_url( site_url( 'wp-login.php?action=register', 'login_post' ) ); ?>" 
    method="post" novalidate="novalidate">

<?php wp_nonce_field( 'ajax_register_nonce', 'register_security' ); ?>
```

O problema é que percebi que haviam várias funções em `javascript` que usavam o mesmo *name* para que fossem executadas.

O que eu pensei foi em também torná-lo dinâmico. Porém não estou conseguindo fazer as funções em `JS` funcionarem.

A função original em `JS` é a seguinte:

```js
register_ajax: function() {
            $('#thim-popup-login form[name=registerformpopup]').on('submit', function(e) {
                e.preventDefault();

                if (!thim_eduma.validate_form($(this))) {
                    return false;
                }

Tentei de várias formas mas não consegui. Tentei colocar um código php dentro do JS mas não deu. Também tentei o seguinte:

    register_ajax: function() {
        $('#thim-popup-login form[name="registerformpopup' + document.title + '"]').on('submit', function(e) {
                e.preventDefault();

                if (!thim_eduma.validate_form($(this))) {
                    return false;
                }
```

Alguém pode me ajudar?

Comment: Tens um erro de sintaxe em `$('#thim-popup-login form['name=registerformpopup ' + document.title]')`... essa concatenação poderia ser `$('#thim-popup-login form[name="registerformpopup' + document.title + '"]')`

Comment: Oi Sérgio, tudo bem? De fato a concatenação estava errado. Obrigado! Mas ainda não funcionou. :(

Comment: Cara, vc não precisa pegar o name do form para usá-lo. Há mts formas de pegá-lo sem usar o name necessariamente.

Comment: Por exemplo: `$("form").on("submit", function(){ $(this) });`...o `$(this)` é o form que foi submetido, não importa o que tem nele.

Comment: No mesmo código php há o formulário de login e de cadastro. Acredito que seja esse o motivo de usar o name.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Você poderia utilizar o [attributeStartsWith](https://api.jquery.com/attribute-starts-with-selector/) do jQuery.
Segue o exemplo do site:

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>attributeStartsWith demo</title>
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
</head>
<body>

<input name="newsletter">
<input name="milkman">
<input name="newsboy">

<script>
$( "input[name^='news']" ).val( "news here!" );
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

O resultado deste HML é o 1° e o 3° input com o texto "news here!", pois somente eles começam com a palavra "news"

Comment: Incrivelmente deu certo, Murilo. Escrevi assim no código JS: 

 `$('#thim-popup-login form[name^="registerformpopup"]')`

Agradeço muitíssimo por compartilhar seu conhecimento.

Comment: Que bom que deu certo! Fico feliz em poder lhe ajudar!